# How to change position of QMenu tearoff?

Tags: qt, qmenu

Is it possible to change the position of the QMenu tearoff subcontrol, to place it on the right ?

I would like to do this :

[image: On left: classic default appeearance. On right : what I want to achieve.]

- The tear-off part is in **red**.
- On **left**: classic default appeearance.
- On **right** : what I want to achieve.

I tried changing the stylesheet with this:

```
QMenu::tearoff {
    background-color:red;
    subcontrol-position: right bottom;
}
```

But with no success. Does anybody have an idea ? I would like to avoid completely reimplementing a custom QMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error, I found a quite simple solution.

You just have to set a new layout to the `QMenu`, which therefore contains a `QMenu` (the one you will fill) and, on the right side (or wherever you want), just insert a `QPushButton` to act as a tear off. When the button is clicked, you can display another menu (which contains the same actions) with `show()`.